# Points of differentiability of the functions $f_n(x)=|x-|x-|x-|x-.......|x-1|||||$, and their convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, sequence-of-function

Consider the functions $(f_n(x))$ defined recursively by
$$f_0(x)=|x-1|$$
$$f_{n+1}(x)=|x-f_n(x)|$$
Then determine the points on $\mathbb{R}$ where the function $f_n(x)$ is differentiable.

Further suppose $$S=\{a \in \mathbb{R} : (f_n(a)) \text{ converges in } \mathbb{R} \}$$

Then to what function does the sequence of functions $(f_n(x))$ converge pointwise on $S$?

**My Attempt**
I was able to find $f_1(x)$ easily. However the analysis becomes complicated for me for higher $n$'s. I feel that induction will help, but I cannot proceed further.

Comment: From the graph it looks like it converges only for $\{2/n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Have you tried proving that?
It also seems to diverge for points that aren't of that form. Have you tried proving that?

Comment: It also looks like the limit $f:S\to\mathbb R$ is $f(x)=x/2$. Have you tried proving that?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I actually got confused about $S$. I couldn't figure it out from the graphs. I feel we need $f_n$'s explicitly to decide